# Use interactive mode for Python PDB in Docker container

Tags: python, docker, sdk

I'm using Docker SDK for python (https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to run a docker image locally. I'd like to set breakpoint and debug by PDB within the docker image. However, the interactive mode is not working, either the docker image seems to be stuck if detach is False, or the docker image enters the breakpoint and doesn't take inputs from keyboard.

I use a simple python script to build a docker image for testing purpose:

```
print("Start ...")
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
print("End ...")
```

Then I create another python script to run the docker image "8b32c9f22884" locally:

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
container = client.containers.run('8b32c9f22884', detach=False, tty=True, stream=True, stdin_open=True)
# If detach is False, it's kinda stuck
# If detach is True, it's not taking inputs
for log_message in container.logs(
    stdout=True, stderr=True, stream=True, follow=True
):
     print(str(log_message, encoding="utf-8"), end="")
return_result = container.wait()
exist_status = return_result["StatusCode"]
```

Does anyone else observe the same issue? If Docker SDK for Python is not working, I guess I need use Python subprocess to call "docker run --interactive" directly.

Comment: Same issue here. Tried different approaches as well but with no success.